# Specific filter for URL popover in post editor

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I'm using WP 5.3 with the default (Gutenberg) editor along with the Polylang 2.7.2 plugin for making the site multilingual. Using Polylang, each post consists of one translation post per language (Polylang groups translation posts together).

Now I have the following problem: When a user is writing a post and tries to link to another already existing post, the search drop down for linking text (Ctrl+K) shows posts in **all** available languages. If the post title isn't language-specific (e.g., "Smart Home") but the "Smart Home" post exists in two languages, it's trial and error for the user to select the one matching the language of the currently edited post:

[image: only one of these posts is in English]

I wanted this URL popover drop down to either only list posts of the same language as the current post, or modifying the results in the drop down to show the specific language (by flag, or "[en]" before the title).

First, I tried using the admin menu bar "Filter content by language" drop down to limit it to English posts - didn't affect the drop down at all.

Next, I tried using a filter to tamper with the query results for this drop down. Using `pre_get_posts` and setting the language hard-coded to English worked:

```
        add_filter('pre_get_posts', [self::class, 'filterQueryLanguage']);
    }

    public static function filterQueryLanguage($query) {
        $query->set('lang', 'en'); // this limits the drop down results to English posts
        return $query;
    }
```

The search drop down then only listed English posts. Unfortunately, this limits **all** queries and it's impossible in the filter function to know for sure if this query originated from an AJAX request by this popover drop down.. also, I didn't manage to detect the language of the currently edited post (`pll_current_language()` returned false in this case).

Therefore, I need a way to post-filter the results only for this popover drop down and prepend the language to the post name in some way. But I have no idea if there even is a filter for this. `get_posts` doesn't seem to fire and even if it did, I don't want to affect all queries.

Are there any more specific filters for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a solution myself. The problem is: this URL popover does a REST API query for `search=phrase`. This search query also has a `lang=` argument that is already set to the appropriate post language - however, when assembling the REST response this `lang` argument is ignored.

I post-filtered the REST result like so:

```
        add_filter('rest_pre_echo_response', [self::class, 'filterRESTResponse'], 10, 3);
    }


    public static function filterRESTResponse($result, $server, $request) {
        $params = $request->get_params();
        if (!empty($params['search']) && !empty($params['lang'])) {
            $filtered = [];
            $lang = $params['lang'];
            foreach ($result as $post) {
                $post_lang = pll_get_post_language($post['id']);
                if ($post_lang === $lang) {
                    $filtered []= $post;
                }
            }
            $result = $filtered;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

This solution is a bit awkward as it might've been possible to make the REST query respect the language from the start. Not sure how to hook into that one, tho.
Well, whatever works.